# NetworkManager: difference between RsnFlags and WpaFlags

Tags: dbus, networkmanager

I'm developing an application that controls NetworkManager through DBus. I'm currently doing some work on the view for access points, and I'm wondering what the difference is between the WpaFlags and the RsnFlags parameters. They both contain values from the NM80211ApSecurityFlags enum.

My tests show that for some access points they contain the same value, but for others they differ. I haven't seen any access points where WpaFlags has a higher value than RsnFlags, leading me to believe WpaFlags contains a subset of the RsnFlags, but I'm not sure.

Is this correct? Does WpaFlags only exist to support legacy applications? Should I use either one or both in my application?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that Rsn is another name for WPA2 :)